# Detecting if string iterator is a blank space

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write a small block of code that detects the most frequently occurring character. However, I've become stuck on not being able to detect if a value is blank space.

Below is the code I have:

```
text = "Hello World!"

## User lower() because case does not matter
setList = list(set(textList.lower()))

for s in setList:
    if s.isalpha() and s != " ":
        ## Do Something

    else:
        setList.remove(s)
```

The problem is that set list ends with the following values:

```
[' ', 'e', 'd', 'h', 'l', 'o', 'r', 'w']
```

I've tried multiple ways of detecting the blank space with no luck, including using strip() on the original string value. isspace() will not work because it looks for at least one character.

Comment: Unexpected things tend to happen if you modify a list that you're currently iterating over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you are removing items from a list while iterating it. **Never do that.** Consider this case

```
['!', ' ', 'e', 'd', 'h', 'l', 'o', 'r', 'w']
```

This is how the `setList` looks like, after converting to a set and list. In the first iteration, `!` will be seen and that will be removed from the `setList`. Now that `!` is removed, the next character becomes the current character, which is . For the next iteration, the iterator is incremented and it points to `e` (since space is the current character). That is why it is still there in the output. You can check this with this program

```
num_list = range(10)

for i in num_list:
    print i,
    if i % 2 == 1:
        num_list.remove(i)
        pass
```

**Output**

```
0 1 3 5 7 9
```

But if you comment `num_list.remove(i)`, the output will become

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

To solve your actual problem, you can use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to find the frequency of characters, like this

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(text.lower())
if " " in d: del d[" "]      # Remove the count of space char
print d.most_common()
```

**Output**

```
[('l', 3), ('o', 2), ('!', 1), ('e', 1), ('d', 1), ('h', 1), ('r', 1), ('w', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A short way is to first remove the spaces from the text

```
>>> text = "Hello world!"
>>> text = text.translate(None, " ")
>>> max(text, key=text.count)
'l'
```

This isn't very efficient though, because count scans the entire string once for each character (O(n<sup>2</sup>))

For longer strings it's better to use `Collections.Counter`, or `Collections.defaultdict` to do the counting in a single pass

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the blank spaces before you start with lists and sets:

```
text = "Hello world!"
text = re.sub(' ', '', text)

# text = "Helloworld!"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the single most frequent, use `max`:

```
text = "Hello World!"

count={}
for c in text.lower():
    if c.isspace():
        continue
    count[c]=count.get(c, 0)+1

print count  
# {'!': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'r': 1, 'w': 1}
print max(count, key=count.get) 
# 'l'
```

If you want the whole shebang:

```
print sorted(count.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]))
# [('l', 3), ('o', 2), ('!', 1), ('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('h', 1), ('r', 1), ('w', 1)]
```

If you want to use Counter and use a generator type approach, you could do:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase

print Counter(c.lower() for c in text if c.lower() in ascii_lowercase)
# Counter({'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'w': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

the above answers are legitimate.  you could also use the built-in count operator if you are not concerned with algorithmic complexity.  For example:

```
## User lower() because case does not matter
text=text.lower()

num=0
most_freq=None

for s in text:
    cur=text.count(s)
    if cur>num:
        most_freq=s
        num=cur
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Also, there is no need to create a list from the characters of the string.  Strings are iterable.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `split()`: it will fail if its blank space:

```
>>> [ x for x in text if x.split()]
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']
>>>
```

To count the duplicate:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> for e in [ x for x in text if x.split()]:
...     d[e] = d.get(e,0) + 1
...
>>> print d
{'!': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'H': 1, 'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'r': 1, 'W': 1}
>>>
```